# div onclick with Form and other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, onclick

I want to fix a problem I have attaching an onclick element to a div ( and only to it! )

Please look at following code :

```
<script>
function  goToo(url,idd){
alert(idd);
if (idd=="onlyMe")
window.location=url;
}
</script>
<div id="onlyMe" onclick="javascript:goToo('http://www.google.com', this.id)" style="<-index:-150">
<form><input type="text" name="coap"></form>

<h3>This is an element where click should work!</h3>

<div id="notME">
<h3>In this point it should not work!</h3>
</div>

</div>
```

I want the onlick to be triggered only in the div clicking.

Please check the example live @ http://modacalcio.com/HtmlProblemForm.html

The click is triggered everywhere, expecially in the form input.

Obiovusly I wish to use this without deleting onclick in children nodes, as they have their own onclick that still need to work

Also with jquery I have same problem
any help?

Comment: Well, if it works in the form, which is inside the div, it is normal behavior.

Comment: yes, it may be normal but I want only to works in the div and not in children, to use maybe as a website background link.  Is it possible?

Comment: Oh. Yes, it is possible. Let me think about it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#onlyMe').on('click', function(evt) {
    if ($(evt.target).parents('#notME').length === 0 && evt.target.id !== 'notME') {
        location.href = "http://...";
    }       
});
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zhkr2/2/

the idea is to check if the event was triggered on `#notME` element or inside an element contained in `#notME`, so I check if an ancestor is that element

Comment: Seeing OP's code, you should definitely state the jQuery dependency :)

Comment: I just noticed the jQuery tag :)

Comment: Oh, I didn't! I guess this answer is fine then.

Comment: Florian you are too nice :D yes I am opened to jqeury solution I have written it in question but maybe is not clear.

This solution works effectively but I need the revers, so to verify that the click comes ONLY BY the only Me and not his children. This because I don't know how many element I can have inside the div I want to be clickable as a background website rotator.

There is no way really to determine which element is triggering the click effectively and not composite ?

Answer (score 0):

just give for 'div' some width

```
#onlyMe
{
width:
height:

}
```

and close the div properly .